# Recovering from a duplicate migration in Django South

Tags: python, django, django-south

Due to merging several feature branches into my project, I have the following migrations:

```
0001_initial.py
0002_auto__add_field_userprofile_telephone__add_field_userprofile_timezone.py
0003_auto.py
0004_auto__del_field_organisation_admin.py
0005_auto__add_field_organisation_permitted_domains.py
0005_auto__add_field_userprofile_currency.py
```

Note that I have two duplicate 0005 migrations. These ran fine, and deployed fine on my production system.

```
$ python manage.py migrate accounts --list                                                                                                                                                              [17:11:42]

 accounts
  (*) 0001_initial
  (*) 0002_auto__add_field_userprofile_telephone__add_field_userprofile_timezone
  (*) 0003_auto
  (*) 0004_auto__del_field_organisation_admin
  (*) 0005_auto__add_field_organisation_permitted_domains
  (*) 0005_auto__add_field_userprofile_currency
```

My table has the correct columns:

```
$ psql
db_my_project=# \d+ accounts_organisation
db_my_project=# \d+ accounts_userprofile
... shows currency and permitted_domain, suggesting the migrations worked correctly
```

However, if I try to create a new migration, South thinks that I haven't added the column' permitted_domains' to my model:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration accounts --auto                                                                                                                                                      [17:16:15]
 + Added field permitted_domains on accounts.Organisation
Created 0006_auto__add_field_organisation_permitted_domains.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate accounts
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/autodetector.html

> When the autodetector runs, it compares your current models with those
>   frozen in your most recent migration on the app, and if it finds any
>   changes, yields one or more Actions to the South
>   migration-file-writer.

The migrations keep a frozen version of the fields within the model in a dict.

Therefore:

In `0005_auto__add_field_organisation_permitted_domains` the Organisation class will have a field `permitted_domains` but in `0005_auto__add_field_userprofile_currency` it will not. When you run:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigrate accounts --auto
```

this will compare the current state of the code against the record of the fields store in `0005_auto_add_field_userprofile_currency`, thus leading south to add the field for a second time.

If you copy the line for the 'permitted_domains' field from `0005_auto__add_field_organisation_permitted_domains` to `0005_auto__add_field_userprofile_currency` this will solve your problem.

Comment: For others referring to this: don't forget to delete the collapsed migration (i.e. `0005_auto__add_field_organisation_permitted_domains` in this case) from the `south_migrationhistory` table, otherwise you'll get this error when you run `migrate <app name>`: `I'm not trusting myself; either fix this yourself by fiddling with the south_migrationhistory table, or pass --delete-ghost-migrations to South to have it delete ALL of these records (this may not be good).`

Answer (score 2):

It is a very specific problem, I hope this helps, do the following:

1) Rename this file: `0005_auto__add_field_organisation_permitted_domains` to `0006_auto__add_field_organisation_permitted_domains`

2) Rename the number of your recently migration file from 0006 to 0007

3) Issue the command `python manage.py migrate account 0006 --fake` to deceive south.

4) Issue the command `python manage.py migrate account 0007`

That might get the south engine in sycn again with your application

Hope this helps!